# 2 Comparison in Java Script - Telegram Bot

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

How Can I USE or for 2 Compare in This Code?

```
//not work  
 if (msg.text != "/start" || msg.text != "Contact us") {
    keyboard.push(["Main Menu","Back"]);
  }

  return keyboard;
}
```

When I Have Just Start it Work

```
 if (msg.text != "/start") {
    keyboard.push(["Main Menu","Back"]);
  }

  return keyboard;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use the AND operator for that, as your condition will always be true. `msg.text` cannot both be `"/start"` and `"Contact us"` at the same time.

Comment: I Called my Keyboard From a Function

Comment: Then What Should I Do?

Comment: @kalsowerus yep that is why `||` is used. `&&` will check for both which it can't be, untill OP shows what the text look like.

Comment: By replacing the `||` with `&&` your condition will be true if `msg.text` is neither of the two strings.

Comment: yessssssss, Solved @kalsowerus

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei Please remember to post an answer and accept it, if you were able to solve your problem yourself ;)

Comment: I Think You Should Post , Because You Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my initial comment:

> Maybe you want to use the AND operator for that, as your condition will always be true. `msg.text` cannot both be `"/start"` and `"Contact us"` at the same time.

By replacing the `||` with `&&` your condition will be true if `msg.text` is neither of the two strings.